# How to infer the type when using generic repository .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working on a project in .Net 5. I have a generic `Repository` class that implements the `IRepository` interface.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync(string url);
}

public class Repository<T>:IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public Repository(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync(string url)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<T>>(jsonString);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also, I have a MyClass Object that implements the IMyClass interface:

```
public interface IMyClassRepository:IRepository<MyClass>
{
    
}

public class MyClassRepository:Repository<MyClassRepository>, IMyClassRepository
{
    public MyClassRepository(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) : base(httpClientFactory)
    {

    }
}
```

In `Startup.cs`, I have registered dependencies as I did in my previous projects.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IMyClassRepository, MyClassRepository>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddHttpClient();
}
```

In the controller, I inject the `IMyClassRepository`. When I call the `GetAllAsync` method, the `JsonSerializer` is not able to convert the result to the `MyClass` type. If I modify this code and return a `string` object, I am able to convert it in the controller. I was wonder how to solve this issue?

Comment: "the JsonSerializer is not able to convert the result to the MyClass type" -- what makes you think that?

Comment: @cantont I got this error: Each parameter in constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory)' on type 'Web.Repository.MyClassRepository' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. The match can be case-insensitive.

Comment: This is not related to the case sensitivity. I use JsonOptions to make it case insensive. Also, I used Newtonsoft.

Comment: `MyClassRepository:Repository<MyClassRepository>` -- you're saying that `MyClassRepository` is a repository which can fetch and store instances of `MyClassRepository`. Therefore when you tried to deserialize, you tried to deserialize as a `MyClassRepository`. You can see this in your error message "on type **Web.Repository.MyClassRepository;**". You probably meant to write `MyClassRepository : Repository<MyClass>`

Comment: @canton7 Thanks so much. That was the problem. That's hilarious. I didn't notice it.

Comment: It's worth reading your error messages :) The fact that you didn't post it indicates that you didn't feel it was important. Learn to understand everything that an error message is telling you!

Comment: In fact, I read the error message several times. I think I should have taken a break and reviewed the code after a while.